# Laravel Blade using if condition inside foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-3, laravel-blade

here is my code ..

```
@foreach (Session::get('show_my_data') as $key1 => $value1)
    <div class="sb_li">
        <input id="sb_system_input_{{ $value1->Myid }}" class="fr_cap" type="text" disabled name="fr_cap[{{ $value1->Myid }}]" value="{{ $value1->FRCapacity }}" maxlength="127"/>
    </div>
    @foreach ($m002_siteinfo as $key => $value)
        @if({{!$value1->name}})
        <div class="sb_li">
            <input id="sb_system_input_{{ $value->Myid }}" class="fr_cap" type="text" disabled name="fr_cap[{{ $value->Myid }}]" value="" maxlength="127"/>
        </div>
        @endif
    @endforeach 
@endforeach
```

I am trying to display values of `Second foreach` which is not there in `first foreach` using `if condition`  in the middle, but iam getting `syntax error` in Laravel ,Blade templete.. any ways to fix this??

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need the `{{ }}` syntax inside the @if

You can just write

```
@if(!$value1->name)
```

Comment: syntax is fixed, but not getting the expected output :(

Comment: What's wrong? Your div inside the @if is not displayed? Maybe you can try other condition like  $value1->name !== ""